# Unity InjectionProperty does not work

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, properties, unity-container

My configuration for a calculator dependent on its' View (GUI) is defined like so (it is then Resolved in the current context):

```
    Dependencies.register<IView, View>(
        "standardView"
    );

    //Register: calculator release configuration
    Dependencies.register<ICalculator, Calculator>(
        "releaseCalculator",
        (new InjectionProperty(
            "IView", 
            Dependencies.resolve<IView>("standardView")
        ))
    );

    //Resolve:
    Calculator theCalculator = (Calculator)Dependencies.resolve<ICalculator>(
        "releaseCalculator"
    );
```

Where Dependencies is a wrapper for an `IUnityContainer`.

The injection-point in `Calculator` is:

```
private IView view;
[Dependency]
public IView IView{
    get{return view;}
    set{view = value;}
}
```

If you wish to see the definition for `Dependencies` please note that it is absolutely equivalent to a projection of unity container except I have extended direct control on lifetime-managers.

The problem is simply; given the above setup, the Property `IView` resolves to null at run-time. It is simply as though Unity just doesn't bloody work.

@Haukinger here is the wrapper:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity;
using Unity.Lifetime;
using Unity.Registration;


namespace Calculator.Utils
{
public static class Dependencies
{
    private static IUnityContainer graph;
    private static List<KeyValuePair<string, LifetimeManager>> lifetimeManagers;


    static Dependencies(){
        //container
        graph = new UnityContainer();
        //instance managers 1 per dependency instance (implementor)
        lifetimeManagers = new List<KeyValuePair<string, LifetimeManager>>();
    }


  //STATES:
    public static void register<I, P>(string alias, params InjectionMember[] injections)
    {
        ContainerControlledTransientManager newLM = new ContainerControlledTransientManager();
        lifetimeManagers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, LifetimeManager>(
            alias,
            newLM
        ));
        graph.RegisterType(
            typeof(I),
            typeof(P),
            alias,
            newLM,
            injections
        );
    }

    //function is identitical to Resolve
    public static T resolve<T>(string alias)
    {
        return (T)graph.Resolve(typeof(T), alias);
    }

    public static void dispose(string alias)
    {
        LifetimeManager target = (ContainerControlledTransientManager)lifetimeManagers.Find((elem)=>(elem.Key.Equals(alias))).Value;
        target.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Named registrations are only injected when you request *all* registered types, i.e. `IView[] allViews`. If you request only one instance, you'll receive the default registration, in your case just `null` as you have no default registration.

Remove the name (`standardView`) and pass `null` as parameter `name` to `RegisterType` and you're good to go.

EDIT: this code works fine at my machine

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IDependency, MyDependency>((string)null);
        var resolved = container.Resolve<Consumer>();
        // resolved.Dependency is an instance of MyDependency
    }
}

internal class Consumer
{
    [Dependency]
    public IDependency Dependency { get; set; }
}

public interface IDependency
{
}

internal class MyDependency : IDependency
{
}
```

Comment: I have changed the alias parameter to null in both the Register and Resolve stages. It STILL resolves to null though. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've built a minimal example with unity 5.6 and it works fine. I suspect a problem with your wrapper.

Comment: Please can I see it?

Comment: Also, I have Unity 5.5.6 but considering what I'm trying to do is so basic I doubt it's a problem.

Comment: Can you add your wrapper to the question, too?